# when hover fasly on list links content of other links also displaying

Tags: jquery

When I move mouse pointer fastly on these tabpane links I'm seeing there is other tab contents also it's displaying , not the content that is active

```js
<!-- Code to show the content on hover -->

var main = function(){
    
 $('#mytabs a').hover(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).tab('show');
          
                  }, function(e){
                   e.preventDefault();
                
                   $('#mytabs li').removeClass('active');
            
                  });
       
       
       
   
}

$(document).ready(main);

This is my HTML code which contains the tabpane list
```

```html
<!-- My tabpanel lists -->

  <div role="tabpanel">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->

   <div class="container">
  
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="mytabs">

     <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Groceries" aria-controls="Groceries" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Fresh food and Groceries</a></li>
     
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#Direct" aria-controls="Direct" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tesco Direct</a></li>

    <li role="presentation"><a href="#clothing" aria-controls="clothing" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">F & F Clothing</a></li>

    <li role="presentation"><a href="#clubcard" aria-controls="clubcard" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Clubcard</a></li>

    <li role="presentation"><a href="#bank" aria-controls="bank" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tesco Bank</a></li>

  </ul>
  
  <!-- My tab panes and the content I'm displaying when hover these links-->

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Groceries">
        <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="" >Start shopping</a></li>
                <li><a href="" >My account </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >My current order </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Delivery slots from &pound 1 </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Favorites </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Delivery saver from &pound 3 </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Prices down </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >New year, new you </a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <img src="/images/links/groceries-15-46-1.jpg"></img>
        </div>
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Direct">
        <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-md-2">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="" >Technology & Gaming</a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Home Electrical </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Home </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Garden </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >DIY & Car </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Sports & Leisure </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Baby & Toddler </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Party & Gifts </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Entertainment & Books </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Toys </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Health & Beauty </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Clothing & Jewellery </a></li>
            </ul>        
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <img src="/images/links/direct-14-44-2.jpg"></img>
    </div>
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="clothing">
        <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-md-2">
            
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="" >Shop F & F Clothing</a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Women </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Men </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Kids </a></li>
                
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <img src="/images/links/clothing-15-47-1.jpg"></img>
        
        </div>
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="clubcard">
        
        <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-md-2">
            
             <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="" >About Clubcard</a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Clubcard Boost </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Clubcard Perks </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >My Clubcard Account </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Clubcard Fuel Save </a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <img src="/images/links/clubcard-15-46-1.jpg"></img>
        
        </div>
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="bank">
         
         <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-md-2">
            
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="" >Current Accounts</a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Credit Cards </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Savings </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Loans </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Mortages </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Car Insurance </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Home Insurance </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Pet Insurance </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Travel </a></li>
                <li><a href="" >Online Banking </a></li>
                
            </ul>        
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <img src="/images/links/bank-14-32-1.jpg"></img>
        </div>
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="realfood">
         
         <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-md-2">
            
            <ul class="list-unstyled">

                <li> <a href="" >Healthy recepies </a> </li>

                <li><a href="" >Cooking on a budget </a></li>

                <li><a href="" >Meal planner</a></li>

                <li><a href="" >Soup recepies </a></li>

                <li><a href="" >Nifty Fifty </a></li>

                <li><a href="" >Simple salads </a></li>

                <li><a href="" >Breakfast recepies </a></li>
                
                
            </ul>        

        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-10">

        <img src="/images/links/realfood-15-47-1.jpg"></img>

        </div>
        
        </div>

    </div>
    
    
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="wine">
         
         <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-md-2">
            
            <ul class="list-unstyled">

                <li><a href="" >Wine by the case </a></li>

                <li><a href="" >Wine Magzine </a></li>

                <li><a href="" >Special Offers</a></li>

                <li><a href="" >Wine Community</a></li>
                
            </ul>        

        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-10">

        <img src="/images/links/wine-15-47-1.jpg"></img>

        </div>

        </div>

    </div>


 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="phoneshop">
         
         <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-md-2">
            
            <ul class="list-unstyled">

                <li><a href="" >Tesco Mobile </a></li>

                <li><a href="" >Pay Monthly </a></li>

                <li><a href="" >Pay as you go</a></li>

                <li><a href="" >SIM Free</a></li>

                <li><a href="" >Mobile Accessories </a></li>

                <li><a href="" >International Calling</a></li>

                <li><a href="" >Tesco Broadband</a></li>

            </ul>        

        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-10">

        <img src="/images/links/phone-15-47-1.jpg"></img>

        </div>

        </div>

    </div>

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="onechange">
         
         <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-md-2">
            
            <ul class="list-unstyled">

                <li><a href="" >Healthy offers </a></li>

                <li><a href="" >Free health checks</a></li>

                <li><a href="" >Pay as you go</a></li>

                <li><a href="" >SIM Free</a></li>

                <li><a href="" >Mobile Accessories </a></li>
                
            </ul>        

        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-10">

        <img src="/images/links/events-15-46-1.jpg"></img>

        </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your code snippet so that it includes the CSS classes you refer to in your jQuery code. (i.e. so that the *"Run this code snippet"* button actually demonstrates your problem.)

Comment: Please don't dump code here. It should reproduce your problem effectively.

Comment: Sorry ... by the way this is my first query in stackoverflow ... my apologies.

Comment: Please help me ... on hover fastly on the tab list I can see the multiple tab contents on my browser ... I don't know what logic I need to apply in my javascript ...